# Getting error while validating token when there are multiple audience in the token

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jwt, access-token, bearer-token

I am getting an error while validating the token. This error occurs when we have multiple audiences in the token.

*"Message": "Jwt10303: Audience validation failed. jwt.Audience: '["/INTERNAL/TEST","/CUSTOMER/SANDPIT"]'. Could not match: validationParameters.AllowedAudience: '/INTERNAL/TEST' and validationParameters.AllowedAudiences: 'null'"*

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(issuer) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(realm) &&
                !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(certificateThumbprint))
            {
                var certificate = GetCertificate(certificateThumbprint);
                if (certificate == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception(Constants.InvalidCertificateThumbPrint);
                }

                tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    AllowedAudience = "/INTERNAL/TEST", 
                    ValidIssuer = issuer,
                    SigningToken = new X509SecurityToken(certificate)
                };
            }

            claims = jwtSecurityHandler.ValidateToken(authenticationToken, tokenValidationParameters);
```

I am using .net framework 4.8 and system.identityModel.Token.Jwt ver 3.0.
I tried to update the system.identityModel.Token.Jwt to 4.0 but then I started getting signature validation failed error.

Another thing I just tried by providing *AllowedAudiences*

```
           tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    AllowedAudience = "/INTERNAL/TEST",
                    AllowedAudiences = new string[] { "/INTERNAL/TEST", "/CUSTOMER/SANDPIT" },
                    ValidIssuer = issuer,
                    SigningToken = new X509SecurityToken(certificate)
                };
```

Even with this, I am getting below error

*{
"Message": "Jwt10303: Audience validation failed. jwt.Audience: '["/INTERNAL/TEST","/CUSTOMER/SANDPIT"]'. Could not match:  validationParameters.AllowedAudience: '/INTERNAL/TEST' and validationParameters.AllowedAudiences: '/INTERNAL/TEST, /CUSTOMER/SANDPIT'"
}*